# Call variable under a PS script as a parameter in Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a config.ps1  script which has a variable "$versionNumber = "1.0.0"". I need enter the variable value of users choice and save the config.ps1 file. I need to do this task using Jenkins Parameter.

My config.ps1 script.

```
#------------------------------------------------
# Pack parameters used to create the .nupkg file.
#------------------------------------------------

# Specify the Version Number to use for the NuGet package. If not specified, the version number of the assembly being packed will be used.
# NuGet version number guidance: https://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning and the Semantic Versioning spec: http://semver.org/
# e.g. "" (use assembly's version), "1.2.3" (stable version), "1.2.3-alpha" (prerelease version).
$versionNumber = "1.0.0"

# Specify any Release Notes for this package. 
# These will only be included in the package if you have a .nuspec file for the project in the same directory as the project file.
$releaseNotes = ""

# Specify a specific Configuration and/or Platform to only create a NuGet package when building the project with this Configuration and/or Platform.
#   e.g. $configuration = "Release"
#        $platform = "AnyCPU"
$configuration = ""
$platform = ""
```

Any possible approach is advisable

My approach--

```
Get-Content c:\config.ps1 | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "$versionNumber = "1.0.0"", "$versionNumber = "$env:version_number" }
```

Output

```
PS D:\> . .\Config.ps1
PS D:\> $versionNumber=1.0.2
PS D:\> $versionNumber
PS D:\> . .\Config.ps1
PS D:\> $versionNumber
1.0.0
PS D:\>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can source your *.ps1 file via the `.` operator. Example:

Test.ps1

```
$test=1234

PS>. ./Test.ps1
PS> $test
1234
```

So in your Jenkins Powershell step you've to call: `. PATHTO\config.ps1`

Comment: how to change the value of $test in this case from 1234 to 4321

Comment: You can perform a simple assign statement like: `$test=4321`